# Applying cross join or cartesian product (database table join) for GeoDataFrames using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, attribute-joins, vector-layer, geodataframe

I have a set of points and I want to calculate the distance from each point to all other points in GeoDataFrame.

This is my GeoDataFrame:

```
    id  Longitude   Latitude    geometry
0   1   -71.275580  46.837460   POINT (-71.27558 46.83746)
1   2   -71.225308  46.814997   POINT (-71.22531 46.81500)
2   3   -71.214790  46.811887   POINT (-71.21479 46.81189)
3   4   -71.215936  46.846704   POINT (-71.21594 46.84670)
4   5   -71.214600  46.812775   POINT (-71.21460 46.81278)
5   6   -71.227372  46.814365   POINT (-71.22737 46.81437)
6   7   -71.353066  46.821339   POINT (-71.35307 46.82134)
```

In fact, if the GeoDataFrame has 3 rows (3 points), I want to have 6 (9-3(each point to itself)) distances. Then, I want to store the distance in front of each set of points.

I thought that if I can do a cartesian product (cross join) of GeoDataFrame with itself, I can then have 2 points in each row and then, calculate the distance for those points (for each row) and write it in front of them in the GeoDataFrame.

How can I do cross join (like tables in databases) in GeoDataFrame?

Do you have any solution for me without cross join (for example, 2 nested loops!)?

I found this answer for cross join in Pandas: [Performant cartesian product (CROSS JOIN) with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699012/performant-cartesian-product-cross-join-with-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```py
# imports
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
# creates a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'Longitude': [-71.275580, -71.225308, -71.214790, -71.215936, -71.214600, -71.227372, -71.353066],
    'Latitude': [46.837460, 46.814997, 46.811887, 46.846704, 46.812775, 46.814365, 46.821339]
    })
# converts the DataFrame to the GeoDataFrame
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)]
df = df.drop(['Longitude', 'Latitude'], axis=1)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry=geometry)
# performs the cross join: "_o" = origin, "_d" = destination
gdf_ = pd.merge(gdf, gdf, how="cross", suffixes=("_o", "_d"))
# erases connections between the same point
gdf_ = gdf_[gdf_["id_o"] != gdf_["id_d"]]
# deletes redundant connections
df_ = gdf_[["id_o", "id_d"]].apply(frozenset, 1)
gdf_ = gdf_[~df_.duplicated()]
print(gdf_)
```

Results into:

```
    id_o                  geometry_o  id_d                  geometry_d
1      1  POINT (-71.27558 46.83746)     2  POINT (-71.22531 46.81500)
2      1  POINT (-71.27558 46.83746)     3  POINT (-71.21479 46.81189)
3      1  POINT (-71.27558 46.83746)     4  POINT (-71.21594 46.84670)
4      1  POINT (-71.27558 46.83746)     5  POINT (-71.21460 46.81278)
5      1  POINT (-71.27558 46.83746)     6  POINT (-71.22737 46.81437)
6      1  POINT (-71.27558 46.83746)     7  POINT (-71.35307 46.82134)
9      2  POINT (-71.22531 46.81500)     3  POINT (-71.21479 46.81189)
10     2  POINT (-71.22531 46.81500)     4  POINT (-71.21594 46.84670)
11     2  POINT (-71.22531 46.81500)     5  POINT (-71.21460 46.81278)
12     2  POINT (-71.22531 46.81500)     6  POINT (-71.22737 46.81437)
13     2  POINT (-71.22531 46.81500)     7  POINT (-71.35307 46.82134)
17     3  POINT (-71.21479 46.81189)     4  POINT (-71.21594 46.84670)
18     3  POINT (-71.21479 46.81189)     5  POINT (-71.21460 46.81278)
19     3  POINT (-71.21479 46.81189)     6  POINT (-71.22737 46.81437)
20     3  POINT (-71.21479 46.81189)     7  POINT (-71.35307 46.82134)
25     4  POINT (-71.21594 46.84670)     5  POINT (-71.21460 46.81278)
26     4  POINT (-71.21594 46.84670)     6  POINT (-71.22737 46.81437)
27     4  POINT (-71.21594 46.84670)     7  POINT (-71.35307 46.82134)
33     5  POINT (-71.21460 46.81278)     6  POINT (-71.22737 46.81437)
34     5  POINT (-71.21460 46.81278)     7  POINT (-71.35307 46.82134)
41     6  POINT (-71.22737 46.81437)     7  POINT (-71.35307 46.82134)
```

---

**References:**

- [Remove reverse duplicates from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474799/remove-reverse-duplicates-from-dataframe)
- [How to remove pair duplication in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303571/how-to-remove-pair-duplication-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: How can I efficiently remove redundant distances such as p1 to p5 and p5 to p1?
I mean removing those rows.

Comment: I hope this is what you were looking for @_@